# Updating jQuery Variable for Stripe Form Functions

Tags: jquery, stripe-payments

I have multiple (hidden by default) Stripe payment forms on a single page site. Depending on the currently active form (displayed with a click event), I need to update the "#some-form" variable in both functions (below) on the same click event. Is this even possible?

```
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#some-form');

    if (response.error) {
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        var token = response.id;
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        $form.get(0).submit();
    }
};

$('#some-form').submit(function(e) {
    expiration = $('.cc-exp').payment('cardExpiryVal');
    Stripe.card.createToken({
        number: $('.cc-number').val(),
        cvc: $('.cc-cvc').val(),
        exp_month: (expiration.month || 0),
        exp_year: (expiration.year || 0)
    }, stripeResponseHandler);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, give all your Stripe forms the same class name, eg 'StripeForm'.

Then modify the submit handler as follows.

```
$(".StripeForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();//<<< more reliable than `return false` at the bottom of the function.
    var expiration = $('.cc-exp', this).payment('cardExpiryVal');//<<< context
    Stripe.card.createToken({
        number: $('.cc-number', this).val(),//<<< context
        cvc: $('.cc-cvc', this).val(),//<<< context
        exp_month: (expiration.month || 0),
        exp_year: (expiration.year || 0)
    }, stripeResponseHandler.bind(this));//<<< .bind()
});
```

Note that `this` refers to the particular form being submitted, and is used :

- as the "context" for the various jQuery selectors
- to give, through the use of `.bind()`, the correct context to `stripeResponseHandler`

Now, because of the `.bind()`, `this` in `stripeResponseHandler`, will also refer to the particular form being submitted.

```
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    var $stripeToken = $("input[name='stripeToken']", this);//<<< context
    if (response.error) {
        $('.payment-errors', this).text(response.error.message);//<<< context
        $('button', this).prop('disabled', false);//<<< context
    } else {
        if(!$stripeToken.length) {//<<< if not previously appended
            $stripeToken = $('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').appendTo(this);//<<< rearranged
        }
        $stripeToken.val(response.id);
        this.submit();//<<< no need for `.get(0)` as `this` already refers to the appropriate form node
    }
};
```

Note that the hidden 'stripeToken' input is appended only if not already present in the form. This will prevent a build up of identical hidden inputs should any of the forms be submitted more than once.

Comment: Thanks! Changed `$stripeToken.val(response.id));` to `$stripeToken.val(response.id);` and that worked perfectly.

Comment: Whoops, erroneous bracket - edited. Be sure to check my changes to the hidden input. Test with visible input elements to make sure multiple instances don't occur.

Answer (score 0):

its not a variable, its a html id. If you want to share code between forms, use classes as your identifer and a unique id per form e.g.:

```
$('.stripeforms').submit(function(e) {

   var id= $(this).attr('id');

   //change your class selectors to e.g.:

   expiration = $(id + '> .cc-exp').payment('cardExpiryVal');     

}
```